# Curve modifier -applying Nurbspath displaces the object

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have attached a blend file with tunnel and path objects.
When I apply object for curve modifier ie Nurbspath, my tunnel moves to a totally different location. 
I have checked all my settings and can't find the source of the problem..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The curve modifier is complex and it takes some playing with it to get used to how it works.  Start by looking at how your objects are orientated in space.

In object mode, the curve is orientated with its X-axis along the global negative Y-axis and the Y-axis along the global X-axis.

[image]

Examine the curve in edit mode.  Your curve is oriented along the Y-axis with the curve normals along the X-axis.

[image]

In object mode, apply (<kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd>) the curve rotation.  Now the object's Y axis points along the curve and the object's X-axis points along the curve's normals.

[image]

The tunnel object is also rotated.  Apply the rotation so the tunnel points along the positive global Y-axis.

[image]

Now add the NurbsPath to the Curve modifier and set the deformation axis to Y.  The tunnel is deformed along the curve, but the roof is lying on the X-axis.  The curve thinks the X-axis is 'up' because its normals point in this direction.

[image]

Select the curve and tab into edit mode.  Select all of the control points and adjust their Tilt by 90 degrees (<kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>).

[image]

Now you can adjust your curve's control points to make a nice, smooth tunnel.  Hint: turn on the Merge option on your array modifier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have to use a nurbs curve. Here I used a bezier curve it fits and plays nicely with the curve modifier.

Blend file here...

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am following the BlenderGuru tutorial on underground tunnels and a path seems to be easier to use. Sorry I am a beginner but I think using a path is more appropriate for this example. I think I followed his instructions closely but can not understand why mine is messed up.

Comment: Usually when the object jumps around when you apply modifier it's due to it's rotation orientiation of the two. Meaning the local rotation axis of the nurbs path and the mesh isn't align in the same axis. You may want to check how you created your objects. Creating a path or curve in the front view is different when you do it in the top view. Depending on the view you use, it will define it's local axis orientation at the moment of creation.

Comment: thanks, I will keep that in mind. I did many things wrong so I started the project from scratch and path works this time for some reason. the reason I wanted to use path is that it starts as a straight line with lots of handles whereas for Bezier I have to do a lot of work just to extend and straighten the curve, rotate each handle etc.